# Vue Computed Value for Class not changing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following component:

```
Vue.component("categorialeaf", {
  props: ["Categoria", "CategoriasFilhas"],
  data: {
        IsOpen: false,
        ClassePrincipal: []
  },
  computed: {
    ObterClassePrincipal() {   
      return this.ClassePrincipal;
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.IsOpen = false;
    this.ClassePrincipal = ["glyphicon-plus-sign"];
  },
  methods: {
    HasChildren: function() {
      return this.CategoriasFilhas.length > 0;
    },
    AbrirSubcategorias: function() {
      this.IsOpen = !this.IsOpen;

      console.log("1: ");
      console.log(this.ClassePrincipal);
      this.ClassePrincipal = [];

      if (this.IsOpen) this.ClassePrincipal.push("glyphicon-minus-sign");
      else this.ClassePrincipal.push("glyphicon-plus-sign");

      console.log("2: ");
      console.log(this.ClassePrincipal);

    }
  },
  template: 
  `<li class="branch">
    <i v-if="HasChildren()" class="indicator glyphicon" :class="ObterClassePrincipal"></i>
    <a href="#" @click="AbrirSubcategorias()">{{ Categoria.Name }}</a>
  </li>`
});
```

When I click on the "a" link which calls the "AbrirSubcategorias" it DOES CHANGE the ClassePrincipal value, but the above "i" class is not changing. I remember that I could put this working before, but I'm not understanding why the computed value is ignoring the "ClassePrincipal" value changes. I also tried to point the "i" class bind directly to data, but nothing.

Another quick answer: Why the initial data values is not working? the "IsOpen" is  undefined, I needed to set it on "created" to start false.

Could someone help me to figure out what is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is you have not specified the `data` property correctly; it must be a function that returns the initial state.

```js
data() {
  return {
    IsOpen: false,
    ClassePrincipal: []
  };
}
```

Refer to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) for more information.

Also `HasChildren` would be better as a computed property instead of a method.

Comment: Thanks Decade. I remember I tried to do data: function() { return ... } } but it also didnt work. I think it would be wrong anyway. Thank you again.

Comment: why I can see some people showing data codes like I did?  "data: { variable: value } }" If I don't put the return it won't be initialized?

Comment: You are only allowed to specify `data` as an object and not a function when the component is being initialized immediately within `new Vue()`. If you are defining a reusable component then `data` must be a factory function so that a new data object instance is created for each instance of that component, otherwise each component instance would share the same data object!